# What is this small gray rat-like mob that emerges from stone in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've come across an unknown animal, it's small, gray and it's emerging from the stone.

It looks like a rat, but theres so many of them. Have I been hacked?

Comment: If you could take a screenshot to add to your question, that would help a lot. Although I am extremely confident in my answer, a screenshot will help me confirm.

Answer (score 9):

**[A Silverfish](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Silverfish)**. Silverfish hide in stone type blocks to emerge when their block is broken or when other Silverfish in the area of a Silverfish block are damaged. You can tell Silverfish blocks from stone observing the mining speed with a pickaxe and with your hand. If a stone block breaks slowly with a pickaxe, and at the same speed with your hand, it has been infested.

Comment: Might also be worth adding the Endermite as well, as they are fairly similar (only difference is there appearance being purple and emerging from Ender Pearls)

Comment: @Ben "grey and emerging from stone" can only be one thing. Though endermites are similar in size, they meet none of the other descriptors, while silverfish absolutely do.

Comment: yeah, I agree with that. If anything it's just an "FYI", but not overly necessary.